# BB10 - Qml debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment

Tags: c++, qt, blackberry, qml, blackberry-10

I'm developing a BlackBerry 10 mobile application using the momentics IDE (native SDK).

When I'm trying to build the project and test it on the device (BlackBerry Dev alpha B), it crashes for no reason and gives the following error:

***" Qml debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment! "***

I really don't know anything about where it comes from, I searched a lot on the internet with no result. Please, does anyone have any idea about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

" Qml debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment! "

That comment is just telling you are running in a development environment, it is not related to your crash.  You need to look for some other messages to find your error.

Comment: Sorry !! I found it, the editor is full of bugs, I don't know but some times the momentics does not precise where the error is located even show if there is some mistakes in the code.